# php - остановка скрипта

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который быстренько делает свое дело и отрубается (загрузка файла)
нужно провести откладку, посмотреть значения переменных, выполнение функций, как это можно сделать?
То есть остановить выполнение скрипта

Comment: exit например можно юзать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция exit и ее синоним die - останавливают выполнение скрипта.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php

Для получения более-мене подробной информации о выполняемом коде используйте ф-ю debug_backtrace

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php

Пример:

```
function foo($a = 0) {
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

foo(43);

array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(14) "php shell code"
        ["line"]=>
        int(1)
        ["function"]=>
        string(3) "foo"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=>
            &int(43)
        }
    }
}
```